# Is there a way to get the dates when the user is login from two tables?

Tags: postgresql

I want to achieve this output:

```
          login          |         logout          
-------------------------+-------------------------
 2019-01-10 09:11:19.639 | 
 2019-01-10 09:38:09.036 | 2019-01-10 09:58:01.41
 2019-01-10 10:00:32.948 | 2019-01-10 10:03:38.515
 2019-01-10 12:06:12.348 | 2019-01-10 12:15:39.531
 2019-01-10 12:16:05.58  |
```

However, I'm getting

```
          login          |         logout          
-------------------------+-------------------------
 2019-01-10 09:11:19.639 | 2019-01-10 09:58:01.41
 2019-01-10 09:38:09.036 | 2019-01-10 09:58:01.41
 2019-01-10 10:00:32.948 | 2019-01-10 10:03:38.515
 2019-01-10 12:06:12.348 | 2019-01-10 12:15:39.531
 2019-01-10 12:16:05.58  |
```

2019-01-10 09:58:01.41 under logout column is duplicating
Please note that they are from two tables. Yes, it is not good practice to put them in separate tables.
But this is the structure of where I'm currently employed.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (login.log_date) login.log_date AS Login, logout.log_date AS Logout
  FROM (
    SELECT login.agent_id, login.session_id, login.log_date
      FROM login
     ORDER BY 3
  ) login
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT logout.agent_id, logout.session_id, logout.log_date
      FROM logout
     ORDER BY 3
  ) logout ON logout.agent_id = login.agent_id AND logout.log_date > login.log_date

 WHERE 1=1
   AND login.agent_id = 123
   AND CAST(login.log_date AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) >= CAST('2019-01-10 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
   AND CAST(login.log_date AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) <= CAST('2019-01-10 23:59:59' AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
;
```

Here are the values

Table Login

```
agent_id  |            session_id            |        log_date         
-----------+----------------------------------+-------------------------
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 09:11:19.639
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 09:38:09.036
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 10:00:32.948
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 12:06:12.348
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 12:16:05.58
```

Table Logout

```
agent_id  |            session_id            |        log_date         
-----------+----------------------------------+-------------------------
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 09:58:01.41
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 09:58:52.634
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 10:03:38.515
 123 | 4ASDASDKASHDAIQUWEHNDADWQENSADPA | 2019-01-10 12:15:39.531
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I'm expecting?
I'm just new here.

Thank you,

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, already edit and added the values of tables.

Comment: Note that the `ORDER BY` in your derived tables (sub-selects) is useless.

Comment: I'll take a note on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by numbering the rows in each table and then use that number for the join:

```
select li.agent_id, li.session_id, li.log_date as login, lo.log_date as logout
from (
  select *, 
         row_number() over (partition by agent_id, session_id order by log_date) as rn
  from login 
) li
  left join (
  select *, 
         row_number() over (partition by agent_id, session_id order by log_date) as rn
  from logout
  ) lo on (li.agent_id, li.session_id) = (lo.agent_id, lo.session_id) 
      and li.rn = lo.rn;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/DLTXU72939